# Yii select2 plugin - style is not getting set in IE

Tags: css, yii, yii-extensions, jquery-select2

I have used ESelect2 plugin in my YII project. In order to set width I have written a class with the value for width element in css file. But the width is not being set in IE browser.For all other browsers the width attribute is getting set as required. For IE I have written a separate css file.
I also noticed that in IE the in-built div arrangement of Select2 plugin is getting mixed up automatically which has not happened in other browsers.

Here is my code.

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.select2.ESelect2',array(
                                'name'=>'list',
                                'id'=>'list',
                                'options'=>array(
                                     'placeholder'=>'Select',
                                    'allowClear'=>true,
                                ),
                                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>"activityeselect2",
                                        'onChange'=>'newval();'
                                ),
                        ));
```

The css file contains the style as `.activityeselect2{width:180px;}`

Thanks

Comment: Is the IE css loaded in IE?

Comment: @Örs - yes the css is loaded in IE. But the styles are not being attached to the select dropdown. Also while inspecting in console the div into which the plugin class(activityeselect2) is attached is different in  IE when compared to other browsers.

Comment: Be sure to add !important to every rule to override anything that is already there. If that doesn't work either, try setting the style with Javascript. [Check on page load if you are in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx#ParsingUA) then add the required styles.

Comment: But the new issue I am into is that the plugin does not render single quotes as itself in IE8. It is shown as &apos; The issue is only IN IE8 and not in any other IE version or browsers